# PHP / MySQL User managment good practice

Tags: php, mysql

For organizing my users table i thought of 2 possiblilties.

1. Having one main "users" table that contains all user informations (about 14 cols)
2. Having a core 'users' table with just 4 columns (ID, Name, mail, pass) and a 'users_info' table that refere to the main 'user' table containing the rest of the info.

What would be the best way to go and why ?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to seperate the information?

Comment: @Mr Wednesday Yes i assumed since this table will be very often queried i might just lighten it up as maximum, and since i am strating this project from scratch i might just get it right from the start. Why -1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure why your question got a -1, let me balance that out for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part you want to try to not create separate tables just for the sake of doing so. For performance, you want to go with your first option, unless maybe you are doing something absurd like having a blob/text column (and even then, it might still not be worthwhile to break it up).

Here is an interesting article about this subject:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_table_normalization.htm

Comment: Interesting read that answers exactly my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of cause 2, and in user_info table, you can just have three column, user_id, info_name, info_value, user_id + info_name as primary key, then you are very easy to add new information in future. And need not save many empty column for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your application. Separating them would make login a bit faster, but would make getting the full user info (e.g. for a profile page) much slower because it would require a JOIN.